# Jquery click event makes the button dissapear

Tags: jquery, adaptive-design

I'm putting together a simplified off-canvas navigation stucture for the mobile version of a site.

I've managed to get everything working except that when the button is clicked for the content to slide into the page, my button disspears.

I thing it must be a simple error in my sintax that's affecting the button and the DIv at the same time. Not sure what though. Here's what I have so far on Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ginmau/YUgVu/

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<body>

     <div class="container">  
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="main_content">
        <header>
            <a class="header-btn-menu">menu</a>
            <h1>ht-design</h1>
            <a class="header-btn-sidebar">sidebar</a>
        </header>

        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi euismod dui non nulla ullamcorper a vulputate turpis bibendum. Praesent interdum tortor sit amet dui pretium facilisis. Quisque sed ante dui, ut vehicula dolor. Mauris ultricies lorem eu diam aliquet nec commodo quam ullamcorper. Nullam diam augue, sollicitudin non laoreet ac, varius non massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed viverra porttitor odio, sed fringilla ipsum aliquet ac. Vestibulum congue iaculis justo, blandit porta lectus facilisis ut. Donec in purus metus, non porta est. Quisque et erat turpis. Etiam egestas nisl cursus ante porta pulvinar. Nulla ac purus eget dolor iaculis lobortis.

Vivamus ac lorem non libero dapibus pellentesque id vel dui. Cras imperdiet commodo magna, vel dictum leo commodo sed. Donec pharetra lacus ligula, et condimentum dolor. Aenean condimentum varius tortor, in interdum tortor egestas non. Mauris interdum, metus a pretium imperdiet, sapien odio vestibulum ante, eget eleifend sem felis quis dolor. Etiam congue posuere magna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce suscipit neque a tortor tincidunt adipiscing. Suspendisse aliquet dui et nunc ultrices id imperdiet massa aliquam. Donec mi sem, facilisis nec consequat eget, sollicitudin at ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada tristique leo, a mollis lacus fringilla a.

Curabitur aliquam consequat neque eget ullamcorper. Donec vitae sodales mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam molestie aliquet felis in sodales. Ut fringilla elementum metus, non venenatis ipsum consequat quis. Phasellus malesuada ipsum sed ipsum accumsan a laoreet urna vehicula. Nam pulvinar nisl ac eros dictum ornare. Nulla scelerisque tincidunt nulla, quis tempor leo porta non.

Nullam cursus felis in neque faucibus hendrerit. Sed malesuada diam ut urna iaculis et laoreet sem viverra. Integer neque nibh, gravida vel vulputate nec, ultricies eu eros. Vivamus facilisis posuere placerat. Suspendisse congue lacus ac tellus laoreet iaculis. Nulla facilisi. Etiam sed velit ut lacus eleifend condimentum ac et mauris. Donec condimentum elementum nisl id elementum. Aenean imperdiet porta suscipit. Donec a ullamcorper dui. Morbi volutpat, magna quis tristique pretium, risus nisl aliquam sapien, dignissim accumsan erat tortor aliquam mauris. Quisque consectetur sapien et massa egestas bibendum. Phasellus dapibus nisi a lorem posuere interdum. Nam sit amet tortor vel risus mollis tempor at vel lorem. Vestibulum at dignissim risus.

Nulla sed nisi at sem tristique porta a sit amet quam. Morbi porta scelerisque orci sed dignissim. Mauris a felis non ipsum fermentum lacinia sit amet id odio. Sed non dolor ipsum, at molestie purus. Ut diam justo, vulputate ut posuere non, bibendum id lacus. Sed sem sapien, hendrerit non hendrerit eu, mattis vitae velit. Vivamus nec tellus sit amet massa mollis pulvinar id sed lacus. Integer fermentum rutrum dolor, et dapibus neque varius ac. Nulla facilisi.
        </section>

        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

**The CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;    
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
}
.slideright {
    left: 240px;
}
.slideleft {
    right: 240px;
}
.header-btn-menu, .header-btn-sidebar {
    display:none;
}
nav, .main_content, aside {
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
nav {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #09C;
}
.main_content {
    width: 60%;
    position:relative;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #09C;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    nav {
        position:fixed;
        left:-240px;
        top:0;
        z-index:1000;
        width: 240px;
        height:100%;
    }
    aside {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .main_content {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .header-btn-menu {
        display:block;
    }
    header a {
        width: 100px;
        height: 25px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    aside {
        position:fixed;
        right:-240px;
        top:0;
        z-index:1000;
        width: 240px;
        height:100%;
    }
    .main_content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .header-btn-sidebar {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

**And last but not least, the javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header-btn-menu").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle(function() {
            $("nav").animate({left: '0px'}, "slow");
            $(".main_content").animate({left: '240px'}, "slow");
        });

    });

    $(".header-btn-sidebar").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle(function() {
            $("aside").animate({right: '0px'}, "slow");
            $(".main_content").animate({right: '240px'}, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).toggle(function() {...
```

Also put the buttons outside the main content.

```
<header>
    <a class="header-btn-menu">menu</a>
    <h1>ht-design</h1>
    <a class="header-btn-sidebar">sidebar</a>
</header>

<div class="main_content">        
    <section>

    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Is effecting the button, take it out and it should work.

```
$(".header-btn-menu").click(function () {
    $("nav").animate({left: '0px'}, "slow");
    $(".main_content").animate({left: '240px'}, "slow");
});

$(".header-btn-sidebar").click(function () {
    $("aside").animate({right: '0px'}, "slow");
    $(".main_content").animate({right: '240px'}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: No @Jessica can you see that his button is also in main_content..??if he apply this way then the button also toggle

Comment: TI orginally had the code without the Toggle function, but then the button only works to slide in the content, not to slide it out :(

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<header>
    <a class="header-btn-menu">menu</a>
    <h1>ht-design</h1>
    <a class="header-btn-sidebar">sidebar</a>
</header>
<div class="main_content">        
    <section>

    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

you are toggling the main_content that contains your button,thats why your button going toggling....put your buttons outside of toggled div and then try

Comment: But if I take the buttons out of the main content, then they won't be affected by the change applied to the main_content DIV

Comment: You want to toggle the main_content div only right..??then what is the need with buttons...

Comment: The buttons are there to toggle the <nav> and <aside> sliding into the page and at the same time adjusting the main_content to slide eaithe left or right as well. I'm trying to create a simplified version of something like this: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/ (push menus)